# Accessing especific XML element from XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello everyboby and thanks in advance,

I have this data in an XML file...

```
<equipos>
<equipo>
    <partidos resultado="ganados">3</partidos>
    <partidos resultado="perdidos">5</partidos>
    <partidos resultado="empatados">2</partidos>
    <partidos pepe="ganados">3</partidos>
    <partidos pepe="perdidos">5</partidos>
    <partidos pepe="empatados">2</partidos>
  </equipo>

<equipo>
    ...
</equipo>

<equipo>
    ...
</equipo>

<equipo>
    ...
</equipo>
</equipos>
```

First of all, is this structure correct? Is so, how can I access from XSL to the value "5" of the specific element

> <"partidos pepe="perdidos">5

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, is this structure correct?

Not sure what you mean by "correct". The input is a well-formed XML document. I don't think we can say anything else without knowing what's the purpose here.

> how can I access from XSL to the value "5" of the specific element
>   `<"partidos pepe="perdidos">`

It depends on your current context. In the absence of that, the absolute path to that element would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/equipos/equipo/partidos[@pepe='perdidos']"/>
```

This assumes the other `equipo` elements do not have a similar `partidos` child.

Comment: Thank you Michael, it worked!, well I've checked with your answer that the structure is correct, I mean, data can be accessed but I think it would be better something like: partidos resultado="perdidos" pepe="perdidos">0</partidos>

Comment: I would need a better understanding of what this is about to answer that. If those duplicate values are not a coincidence, then it seems you only have 3 `partidos` - and that `resultado` is always equal to `pepe`, so why list them both?

Comment: OK Michael, you see, I'm doing a course about web programming technologies. Now we're learning XML - XSL, and this question it was about how to access if you have a node with the same element (partidos) with different attributes(resultado, pepe) with the same values for both but different for each one values(ganados, perdidos, empatados) and finally with different element values(3,5,2). A classmate told me that this kind of data access it was not possible, but YOU have revealed that he was absolutely wrong. So this is really an example, just to learn for possible real cases, Thanks again!.